# Making a custom background in Joomla subway theme

Tags: joomla, background, web, themes, directory

I'm relatively new to Joomla. I do have some experience and can make a pretty good website though. What i am struggling with is importing my own background image into the subway theme? I have done some searching and people keep saying to overwrite one of the images in the 'background' folder. Seems simple enough, except that this folder doesn't seem to exist anywhere! Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder must exist. You should be looking for

```
templates/yoo_subway/images/background/
```

Then you will have a choice of 8 folders, depending on what preset you are using for the template.

If you still somehow seem to struggle with this, please provide a website link.

Regards

Comment: I was trying to do all of this in Joomla! Just entered my ftp client and it's sorted! Thanks for the help :)